# The TargetControlID of 'ModalPopupExtender1' is not valid. A control with ID 'lbview' could not be found

Tags: asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvstudent" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" OnRowCommand="gvstudent_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LName" HeaderText="Surname" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Technology" HeaderText="Technology" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbview" CommandName="cmdView" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server">View</asp:LinkButton>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" CommandName="cmdDelete" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lbview link button is in an item template, so its ID changes when the gridview data binds, it would be something like gvstudent_ctl00_lbview in the end

Consider using the client-API of the MPE: $find("<%=theModalPopupExtenderID.ClientID%>").show() and call that from the client click o nthe lbview. And, do not forget to cancel the postback.

Or, take a look here for a similar scenario that uses JS: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/controls/examples/integration/gridandwindow/defaultcs.aspx?product=window.

Comment: What will be the id of that linkbutton after data bind? what should i specify as a targetcontrolid of a modalpopupextender.

Comment: That's what I am saying - you cannot know what it will be. Redner a page and inspect it with the browser dev toolbar to see examples, but if something in the page structure changes, so will these IDs. ALso, you will have many such buttons, one for each record in the datasource. This is why you will need the client API of the popup to show it. This cannot happen with a simple property.

Comment: ok, Is there any alternate way that can provide me functionality like when i click on view ( which is linkbutton inside gridview ) . I want to show that record on any other control.

Comment: I did show you two in my answer. Read it, then do some reading on what an IScriptControl is, what $find() is and what JavaScript is.